# Dart Editor stops highlighting errors when using "part of"

Tags: compiler-errors, dart, syntax-highlighting, dart-editor

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the Dart Editor, or a problem with the way I'm using `part of`, but given the following project structure:

```dart
myapp/
    pubspec.yaml
    pubspec.lock
    asset/
    packages/
    build/
    web/
        Fizz.dart
        Buzz.dart
```

Where `Fizz.dart` is:

```dart
library fizz;

void herp() {
    print("Herp!");
}
```

and where `Buzz.dart` is:

```dart
library buzz;

void derp() {
    String x = "Derp!";
    print(x);
}
```

If I change `Buzz.dart` to intentionally have a compiler error:

```dart
library buzz;

void derp() {
    djedString x = "Derp!";  // Produces "Undefined class 'djedString'" error
    print(x);
}
```

Then Dart Editor underlines `djedString` with a red line and gives the above compiler error:

> Undefined class 'djedString'

But if I then change `Buzz.dart` to be a `part of` the `fizz` library:

```dart
part of fizz;

void derp() {
    djedString x = "Derp!";  // Perfectly fine! No errors!
    print(x);
}
```

Dart Editor then **removes the compiler error**, and in fact, stops looking for warnings/errors altogether (inside the file).

Is this a bug or am I not using `part of` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`part of aaa;` have to be used with `part "xxx";`.

**a.dart**

```dart
library a;

part 'a1.dart';
```

**a1.dart**

```dart
part of a;

// content of the part
```

Comment: You have to link it **both ways?!?!?** That's *insane*!!! That's **really** annoying...I can't imagine it's actually necessary for compilation/linking...uggh. Thanks though, your suggestion "fixed" it! I'll give you the green check in a few mins when SO allows me.

Comment: You can see [this discussion on the misc dart group](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/OLTlR7aIOP4/0aMjyoA1rO0J) for more explanations on the double link.